# Post Data for CakePHP Controller Unit Test

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp-2.0

I'm writing a Unit Test for one of my controller methods which requires some post parameters. Therefore, I try to pass it along with calling testAction like this:

```
$post_data = array("param1" => "value1", "param2" => "value2");
$this->testAction("/path/to/action", 
                  array('data' => $post_data, 'method' => 'post'));
```

But the values are not available in my controller method. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: what is the problem passing parameter or accessing paramaters in the controller?

try printing $_REQUEST in the controller method